# ASN.1 AUTOMATIC TAGS and EXTENSIBILITY IMPLIED Attributes

Tags: asn.1

I have been presented with an ASN.1 document that includes two encoding/decoding attributes;

- AUTOMATIC TAGS

  - My understanding; the tags are defined automatically using the encoding rules unless a tag notation is present in the definition
- EXTENSIBILITY IMPLIED

  - My understanding; types may have elements that are not defined within the ASN.1 document. If found, the encoder should silently ignore. *Additionally, my decoder should also be ready to handle values with unspecified tags.*

**Q1:** Are my understandings above correct?

**Q2:** w.r.t AUTOMATIC TAGS; defining automatically seems infeasible (obviously not...) but my understanding is that `someEncoder` would therefore assign `SomeType.class` with tag (for example) `0xBB`; how does `someDecoder` know how to decode `0xBB` back to `SomeType`?

**Q2:** w.r.t unspecified tags; once again, I am unsure how to pass an unspecified Tag back to something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1. If the `AUTOMATIC TAGS` clause is present, all the components of the
`SEQUENCE` and `SET` types and all the alternatives of the `CHOICE` types
defined in the module are automatically tagged sequentially starting from 0. If a constructed type contains at least a manual tag
(i.e. if it contains square brackets), the automatic tagging mode is
switched off for this type.

Q2. The same algorithm for automatic tagging is used when writing the encoder and decoder code.

Q3. Your decoder may encounter unrecognized tags when it is communicating with a peer which has a newer version of your ASN.1 schema (which includes additional components). In this case (if you do not intend to retransmit the received data) you should ignore the unrecognized tags.

Comment: Thank you! That clears things up for me; one final thing, I presume BER/DER is fine for both AUTOMATIC TAGS and EXTENSIBILITY (I cannot figure why it would not be) -- I am not keen on writing a PER encoder/decoder.

Comment: Yes, BER/DER will work fine with AUTOMATIC TAGS and EXTENSIBILITY. I understand that you want to manually write the encoder and decoder. This may be required if you need something which is optimal from a size and performance point of view. But in most situations, you should use an ASN.1 compiler to generate the code for the encoder and decoder and also for the data structures.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find anything that's free for use with Java, that also supports the ASN1 spec I've received. I have found a perhaps 65% complete implementation from Apache Harmony, and I've added a lot to the base types. I have managed to use a compiler to extract the models from the spec (i.e. application specific stuff) so I figure I may be able to do this myself. Famous last words.